# how can I export the contents of a virtual directory change some paths and then reimport

Tags: powershell, iis-6, adsi

I'm using IIS6

using powershell I would like to export a specific virtual directory to a file, change the name and some paths and then reimport the data, creating a new virtual directory

It looks like [IISComputer.Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524506%28v=vs.90%29) would do the job but try as I might I can't get it to work

Comment: You might want to also try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Christian I have been uising the ADSI functionality which means I can connect to the server, but whenever i check Get-Member I can never find the Export Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found

From the link here [MSDN DirectoryEntry.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz4574y2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I worked out that I would be able to copy the virtual directory then set the properties manually

From there I came up with the following powershell code which lets my clone a virtual directory then re point it

```
$vd = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/CurrentVd"

$parent = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root"

$vd.CopyTo($parent,"NewVd")

Set Application Pool
$vd.AppPoolId = "MyNewAppPool"

Set Virtual Directory
$Vd.Path = "C:\MyNewTargetPath"

$parent.CommitChanges()
```